# Условие CHECK при создании таблицы в MySql

Tags: mysql

Создаю таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE MBank.Activity (
activity_id bigint AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
client_id bigint,
amount double,
activity_date DATE,
commission double,
description text NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES MBank.Clients(client_id),
CHECK(amount > 0),
CHECK(description IN 
('withdraw', 'deposit', 'account closing', 'deposit ending', 'deposit pre-opening'))
);
```

По идее условие CHECK(amount > 0) должно гарантировать мне, что в столбец amount нельзя будет добавить отрицательное значение (командой INSERT). Но на деле оно просто не выполняется. В чём проблема?
установлена последняя версия MySql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. - Предложение ПРОВЕРКА распознается, но игнорируется всеми механизмами хранения.
Cмотрим [тут](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html).